# How to retrieve the result of a Firebird INSERT ... RETURNING in Yii

Tags: php, yii2, firebird

I am trying to use Firebird 2.1 with Yii (using plugin http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-firebird/) but I have problems doing insert (save) commands, the error message is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -502 Cursor is not open

I have found that Yii generates insert statement with returning clause, **e.g.:**

```
INSERT INTO CONTRACTS (contract_no) VALUES (10002) RETURNING contract_no
```

And I guess that the problem is the following: Yii tries to read results from this insert command but there are problems with Yii-Firebird plugin which closes cursors immediately after `pdoStatement->execute`. The exception is generated in `yii/db/Command.php` file function *`protected function queryInternal($method, $fetchMode = null)`* whose code reads:

```
 $this->pdoStatement->execute();

 if ($method === '') {
     $result = new DataReader($this);
 } else {
    if ($fetchMode === null) {
        $fetchMode = $this->fetchMode;
    }
    try {
        $result = call_user_func_array([$this->pdoStatement, $method], (array) $fetchMode);
        $this->pdoStatement->closeCursor();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        Yii::trace('Fetch error', 'yii\db\Command::query');
    }
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. Does anyone uses Firebird with Yii, what the experience is?
2. How to explain code:

   `call_user_func_array([$this->pdoStatement, $method], (array) $fetchMode);`

and where to correct it? I guess that this method should be overriden in Yii-Firebird plugin with the aim to check whether the cursor is open and, if necessary, open the cursor?

Comment: An `INSERT .. RETURNING` in Firebird behaves the same as an executable stored procedure (ie a stored procedure with return values, but without `suspend`). It doesn't produce a result set from the perspective of the server, it just returns a single row as the result. So if you know how to execute an executable stored procedure in Yii, then you can use the same method for `INSERT ... RETURNING`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of PHP PDO with Firebird INSERT... RETURNING / STORED PROCEDURE without SUSPEND](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39448052/use-of-php-pdo-with-firebird-insert-returning-stored-procedure-without-susp)

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the first question.
With the YII2 I use *"edgardmessias/yii2-firebird": "^0.7.1",* extension for Firebird 2.1.1883. 
I found that it better to work not with ActiveDataProvider, but with

> $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([

in the SearchModel. That way are not so much errors while searching with relation.
But main problem is case sensitive search. I always needed to write in the search field same letters what record have, Big or small.