# Use of PHP PDO with Firebird INSERT... RETURNING / STORED PROCEDURE without SUSPEND

Tags: php, pdo, yii2, firebird, yii-extensions

I have PHP code that executes PDOStatement and tries to fetch the returned data:

```
$this->pdoStatement->execute();
$this->pdoStatement->fetch();
```

The SQL of PDO statement is:

```
INSERT INTO CONTRACTS (contract_no) VALUES (10010) RETURNING contract_no
```

But the stored procedure without suspend clause can also be here. The problem is that the mentioned sequence of PHP PDO commands return the following error while executing fetch:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -502 Cursor is not open
```

How and is it possible at all to get data from insert... into from Firebird using PHP Data Objects PDO?

This question has a wider context - I try to use Yii 2.0 with Firebird using plugin http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-firebird/ and I have discovered that the insert command is not working due the problem described in this question.

Firebird 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading PHP. I've fixed some bugs in the PHP7 Firebird PDO extension, including statements with "returning" clause.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17378599)

Comment: It is a solution. I'm sure an upgrade of PHP would help.